# Mathematica package for power spectra of scalar perturbations

Tags: packages, physics

Is there any Mathematica package available to numerically compute the power spectra of the scalar and tensor perturbations in cosmology? I'd like to numerically calculate the tensor to scalar ratio in inflation. I've tried to search the literature but I can't find some papers or sources doing this or has this package. Maybe there are other ways to numerically calculate the tensor to scalar ratio?

Answer (score 2):

In case you still need such a package, there is a paper [arXiv:1502.03125](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03125) which includes a *Mathematica* code doing this job.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to actual code?

Comment: Yes, sure.  https://github.com/mafaldadias/mTransport  .But I suggest you to read the paper first to understand how it works and modify the code to your needs. It's impossible to understand the code itself.

Comment: @PaulSchrednicki can you repackage their stuff as a single function / alg? To my eyes, it looks they're not used to using Mathematica concisely and are being overly complicated with the code. A simple answer rather than a bloated notebook would be better.